# remove the list symbol from array

Tags: python, list

I have the elements stored in an array, but they are stored inside a list. How do I get them without the list involved? This is what I mean

```
for folders in os.listdir(folder_path):
    for folder in os.listdir(folder_path+folders):
        if folder == 'images':
            image_file = os.listdir(folder_path+folders+'/'+'images'+'/')
            allFileNames.append(image_file)`
```

What I get is

```
for i in allFileNames:
    print (i)


['a31deaf0ac279d5f34fb2eca80cc2abce6ef30bd64e7aca40efe4b2ba8e9ad3d.png']
['308084bdd358e0bd3dc7f2b409d6f34cc119bce30216f44667fc2be43ff31722.png']
['5953af5080d981b554529971903d8bee9871457a4361b51f04ba04f43793dd8f.png']
```

What I would ideally like is

```
'a31deaf0ac279d5f34fb2eca80cc2abce6ef30bd64e7aca40efe4b2ba8e9ad3d.png'
'308084bdd358e0bd3dc7f2b409d6f34cc119bce30216f44667fc2be43ff31722.png'
'5953af5080d981b554529971903d8bee``9871457a4361b51f04ba04f43793dd8f.png'
'29dd28df98ee51b4ab1a87f5509538ecc3e4697fc57c40c6165658f61b0d8e3a.png'
```

Any suggestions on how I may do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just replace

```
allFileNames.append(image_file)
```

by

```
allFileNames.extend(image_file)
```

Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python) for more details.

Comment: It is very well explained in the thread I linked. `append` will add a list to an existing list while `extend` adds  the elements to the existing list. So difference is that you end up with only one list instead of a list of lists.

Comment: Thanks a lot  @cleb

Answer (score 1):

You can try with Generators:

```
  allFileNames = (os.listdir(folder_path+folders+'/'+'images'+'/') 
                    for folders in os.listdir(folder_path) 
                    for folder in os.listdir(folder_path+folders) if folder == "images")
  print(*list(allFileNames),sep="\n") #In python 2, need to import this from __future__ import print_function
```